# Apply stroke to path object

Tags: path

I want to render a path, without generating a mesh/geometry. Can I render this circle path with a black line? For example using this stroke object in the scene.

[image]

Trying to do this as simple as possible. I added a cube to emphasize I still want to do 3d, I am not interested in creating a Greace Pencil scene.

I know this possible in Cinema 4D but I can't find it in blender. [Here is an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrwg4ljzaEk), where a text in a path object is being rendered without adding mesh/geometry.

Comment: For example, this guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsywSvBG4t8 was able to add a stroke without creating geometry or a 2d scene.

Comment: Have you tried freestyle? Freestyle and grease pencil are the closest to C4d sketch and toon

Comment: Thanks @Emir might be a solution from what I can see on a quick search. You suggestion lead me to this, a possible duplicate of my question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78588/whats-the-best-way-to-take-a-bezier-curve-and-have-it-render-as-a-freestyle-lin

Answer (score 1):

### tmp Answer

Have you found the link in your comment as solution for you?
Because with that you can just set a **Bevel > Depth 0.001** for your *Bezier Circle* and it works for me ...

[image]

It is not clear to me if also this technique is considered by you as generated geometry :)

With *Bevel > Depth* you don't even need the *Grease Pencil* at all ... just assign black color to material *Output* node. The result would be the same.

---

I thought *Grease Pencil* keeps thickness of **Line Art** modifier constant in render, but it doesn't (curves far from camera are thinner than close one).

[image]

To keep thickness in perspective render **Freestyle** works fine (just to render curve you would have to set some minimal *Bevel > Depth* anyway).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input :) I think it's simply not possible in blender.. I also see that the grease pencil as you point out as well, has dept